# Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools/read Error

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am following this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/how-to-pause-resume-pipelines to get the list of SQL pools,
but facing the error: The client 'XXXXX' with object id 'XXXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools/read' over scope '/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/workSpaceName' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

Could you please guide what and where to grant permission to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to grant permissions to that specific user on the `Azure Synapse Workspace` data plane using the following steps:

1. Go you your `Azure Synapse Workspace` resource.
2. Then, under `Getting started` Open `Synapse Studio`.
3. Go to `Manage`, and under `Security` label, Select `Access control`.
4. Click `+ Add`.
5. Add Role Assignment to the user with:

   - `Workspace` Scope.
   - `Azure Apache Spark Administrator` Role.